# Laravel & Vue - separate assets for admin and public page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, content-management-system

I'm new to Vue but I really like it. Right now I have my own CMS based on Laravel. I want to build new CMS as SPA in Vue. But one thing is not clear to me. How should I separate assets for frontend and admin?
For example I would like to have COMPONENTS folder with another folder ADMIN - there will be only admin components.
I also don't want to have webpack building everything together.
I was thinking about solution like having multiple webpack commands:

```
npm run dev
npm run dev admin
```

But maybe I'm completely wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have 2 different commands - you just need to specify different configuration files to `webpack --config` option
like:
package.json

```
{  
   "scripts": {
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
   "dev-admin": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev-admin.conf.js",
   }
}
```

Another option is to use webpack`s "multiple pages" option. It would allow you to build 2 entry .js files and all of the chunks for both of your apps.

Take a look here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application

And if you use Vue-cli - https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages